# Do I.I.D. n-tuples have the same distribution when shifted?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, stationary-processes

Suppose as an example with $n=3$ we have that $X_1, X_2, \dots$ is a sequence of random variables satisfying the condition that $(X_1,X_2,X_3), (X_4,X_5,X_6), (X_7,X_8,X_9), ...$  and so on are all i.i.d. $3$-tuples. Does this imply that, for example, $(X_2, X_3, X_4)$ and $(X_3, X_4, X_5)$ are i.i.d.?

I certainly know that our condition above doesn't imply that all of the individual $X_i's$ are i.i.d. and could quickly construct a counter-example. However I can't think of a counter-example disprove the possibility of these shifted $3$-tuples being i.i.d. Either a counter-example or some sketch of a proof showing why they're i.i.d. would be greatly appreciated.

I also suspect this has some relation to the concept of stationarity.

Comment: @lulu : I am not assuming that $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are independent copies. I am assuming that the 3-tuple $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ is independent from and identically distributed to the 3-tuple $(X_4, X_5, X_6)$, and so on.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  Completely misread your post.

Comment: It seems you might have mis-phrased your question, because Jose's answer makes it seem too easy. An interesting question would be whether or not $(X_1,X_2,X_3),(X_4,X_5,X_6),\dots$ being iid implies $(X_2,X_3,X_4),(X_5,X_6,X_7),\dots$ being iid. Is that what you meant to ask?

Comment: @MikeEarnest Good point! The answer to that question is still no. I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @JoseAvilez Thank you for addressing that, nice construction :^)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are not IID. Recall that if two random vectors $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then so are all Borel images $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ of them.

Arguing by contradiction, suppose $(X_2, X_3, X_4)$ and $(X_3,X_4,X_5)$ are indepedent. If we take $f = \pi_2$ and $g=\pi_1$ (the projections onto the second and first coordinates, respectively), then you get $X_3 = f(X_2, X_3, X_4) = g(X_3,X_4,X_5)$, meaning that $X_3$ is independent of itself. This cannot happen if $X_3$ is not a constant.

**Edit:** In case you meant to ask the variant of this question proposed by @MikeEarnest in the comments, the answer is still no. To see this, we let the tuples $\vec{X}_i = (X_{3i-2}, X_{3i-1}, X_{3i})$ by IID as $i$ varies, but chosen so that $X_{3i-2} = X_{3i-1}$. Then, the vectors $(X_2, X_3, X_4)$ and $(X_5, X_6, X_7)$ cannot be independent by considering the projections $\pi_1$ and $\pi_3$ and observing $$\pi_1 (X_5, X_6, X_7) = X_5 = X_4 = \pi_3 (X_2, X_3, X_4)$$
implying the proposed random vectors are not independent.